# Combining Two Files

Tags: php, combiners

Thanks in advance for helping me in this issue,

I have two files

**file1.txt** which contains:

```
adam
william
Joseph
Hind 
Raya
```

and **file2.txt** which contains:

```
Student
Teacher
```

What I want is to combine the two files in one file in this way, so that when the `eof` of **file2.txt** is reached, it re-reads it again and continue the

Combined.txt:

```
adam
Student
william
Teacher
Joseph
Student
Hind 
Teacher
Raya 
Student
```

Comment: Okay, have you tried anything yet? Maybe `file_put_contents('Combined.txt', file_get_contents('file1.txt') . file_get_contents('file2.txt'))`?

Comment: It is possible, read each file with php, and use an loop to loop the function, and combine it using the .= function.

Comment: This smells like homework to me.

Comment: @bassxzero that would explain why it's urgent :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by looping the first text file's lines and inserting the alternate lines from text file #2 using a modulus on the key. The calculation is `list #2 key = the remainder of list #1 key divided by the number of lines in list #2`, i.e. `$list2Key = $list1Key % $numberOfLinesInList2`. More info on [the modulus operator here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

```
$f1 = file('1.txt');
$f2 = file('2.txt');

$number_of_inserts = count($f2);

$output = array();
foreach ($f1 as $key => $line) {
    $output[] = $line;
    $output[] = $f2[$key % $number_of_inserts];
}

print_r($output);
```

This will work with any number of rows in the second text file.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution @robbie,
can you show how to write the array into the file merge.txt

Comment: File put contents will do that for you